# Get authorId from Device - android

Tags: android, google-play

I am using Android Market api.
I use it to retrieve all the comments to my app:
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToGetAppComments

My question is how can I know what is the authorId of the current user? 
I just need to know if that user already  write a comment or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code at the link you posted shows this:

```
public void onResult(ResponseContext context, CommentsResponse response)
{
    System.out.println("Response : " + response);
    // response.getComments(0).getAuthorName()
    // response.getComments(0).getCreationTime()
    // ...
}
```

Based on the [source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#EplFq6Mp1zQ/trunk/AndroidMarketApi/src/com/gc/android/market/api/model/Market.java&q=authorid%20package%3ahttp://android-market-api%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=4120) , to get the`authorID` of the first comment for example, you should be able to use

```
String id = response.getComments(0).getAuthorID();
```

Comment: This is not my question. I know how to get the AuthorID from a comment. but I don't know how the get the AuthorID from device Or user. To be more clear I need to know what is the AuthorID and How can I get it from a userName or phone?